# Is it possible to add JOIN query with SUM and GROUP BY in SQL for the following query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can read "cust_id" and their dues with the following query in one table called 'incomes' but I have names and address in other table called customer - what I need to add with the query - is it possible to add JOIN query with the following? how?

```
SELECT cust_id, SUM(inc_text)- (SUM(inc_amount)-  
       SUM(
           case
               when inctype_id =11 then 0
               else inc_amount
           end
       )) Total_due_left  FROM incomes 
                                
  GROUP BY cust_id;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT c.*,
       ( SUM(i.inc_text) - (SUM(i.inc_amount) - SUM(CASE WHEN i.inctype_id = 11 then 0 ELSE inc_amount END))
       ) as Total_due_left
FROM incomes i JOIN
     customers c
     ON c.cust_id = i.cust_id                             
GROUP BY c.cust_id;
```

This works assuming that `customers.cust_id` is the primary key (or at least declared `unique`) in `customers`.  Otherwise you need to list the columns explicitly in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

It also looks like this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT c.*,
       ( SUM(i.inc_text) - SUM(CASE WHEN i.inctype_id = 11 THEN inc_amount ELSE 0 END)
       ) as Total_due_left
FROM incomes i JOIN
     customers c
     ON c.cust_id = i.cust_id                             
GROUP BY c.cust_id;
```

Comment: yes this is the solution of the problem and yes "customer.cust_id" is the unique and primary key. Thank you a lot sir.